# How to undo a grammer rule saved by Outlook 365 desktop by mistake

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, spell-check, grammar

So I type a line that is NOT supposed to end in a period. It was a line of text that was not meant to have a period, like a poem. Outlook grammar asks if I always want to ignore this error and not bug me again.

I clicked Yes to not have it check again, and that was not what I should have done since now I can freely write any sentence, like this one, with no period at the end

How can I undo that. DOH!

Comment: That’s only a rule for the existence of the email (I.e until it’s sent)

Comment: Nope, not just for the one email.  Same on any new email now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically, you can make sure the highlighted options below are selected:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's probably one of the options in the Grammar Settings. (To be honest, for me with default settings in Outlook 2021, Outlook doesn't grammar check for missing paragraph period.)

- Go to **File** > **Options**
- In the **Mail** tab, click on **Spelling and Autocorrect**
- In the ***Editor Options*** window, go down to ***Writing Style*** and click **Setting**
- Click on **Reset All** to put back all rules to the default

[image]